# Magento search Rest API how to get products all the detail in the response?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, search-criteria, search-terms

I want to get product all the detail in Search Rest Api response but Magento default is returning only id and custom_attributes attributes.

Api :- `http://127.0.0.1/magento/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=MS09

Response :-

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "id": 484,
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "score",
                "value": "607.6608886718750000"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"aggregations": {
    "buckets": [
        {
            "name": "category_bucket",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "12",
                    "metrics": [
                        "12",
                        "1"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "value": "16",
                    "metrics": [
                        "16",
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bucket_names": [
        "category_bucket"
    ]
},
"search_criteria": {
    "request_name": "quick_search_container",
    "filter_groups": [
        {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "field": "search_term",
                    "value": "MS09",
                    "condition_type": "eq"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"total_count": 1
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Search endpoint is public so the details are not included. For all product details you should use the products endpoint. You need an admin token in your header to get the information. If MS09 is your sku, the URL would be http://127.0.0.1/magento/rest/V1/products/MS09

See docs here for reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/search-endpoint.html